# django: sort rows based on number of column matching

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model:-

```
class Userprofile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    education=models.models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    occupation=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)     ....
```

for a user profile (let's say: ('masters','India','student') I want to filter all the user profiles ordered by the number of fields it matches with the given user profile i.e first all 3 fields matching profiles then any 2 fields matching profiles and so on.Can anyone suggest a way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions).

```
from django.db.models import Value, Case, When, IntegerField, F

education, country, occupation = 'masters','India','student'
Userprofile.objects.annotate(education_matched=Case(
    When(education=education, then=Value(1)), 
    default=Value(0), 
    output_field=IntegerField()
), country_matched=Case(
    When(country=country, then=Value(1)), 
    default=Value(0), 
    output_field=IntegerField()
), occupation_matched=Case(
    When(occupation=occupation, then=Value(1)), 
    default=Value(0), 
    output_field=IntegerField()
)).
annotate(matched=F('education_matched') + F('country_matched') + F('occupation_matched')).
order_by('matched')
```

Comment: there is a ")" missing before .order_by('matched'). Also, it was showing error earlier but when I renamed the field "occupation_matched"  to some other name it worked.

Comment: Added missing '('. If it works can you accept answer?

Comment: it showed me error sometime and sometime it worked.
    FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'education_matched' into field.

Comment: Fixed. I split annotate into 2 annotate.

Comment: yes it worked. what was the reason for the error in the earlier query? was it because of the order of execution?

Comment: Yes, annotate randomly add your statements into sql and sometimes it can have incorrect order, but now it firstly add statements from first annorate and then from second.